# How to Execute SVN Update command through SQL xp_CMDShell

Tags: sql, svn, xp-cmdshell

I have installed Tortoise SVN on my machine, i want to update my local copy with SVN using SVN UPDATE command. I am using SQL script

```
 EXEC master..xp_CMDShell 'svn update D:\SVN_WorkingFolder'
```

This script is not executing. May i know where i am doing workng.

Thanks in advances guys.
KumaR

Comment: Does "svn update D:\SVN_WorkingFolder" work from a normal command line prompt?

Comment: Yes, SVN update works on command prompt.. I have tried SVN CLEANUP command which is working fine. EXEC master..xp_CMDShell 'svn cleanup D:\SVN_WorkingFolder', but SVN UPDATE is not working.

Comment: Does xp_CMDShell support output redirection? If yes, you could try svn update D:\SVN_WorkingFolder > D:\svn_update_log.txt - perhaps the command output will tell you why it fails.

Comment: Hai Frank, i creaked the solution. it is issue with permissions to access network. Now i can do svn update. Thanks for your efforts.

Comment: Then I'd suggest you add an answer to your own question in which you describe how you solved it (so if someone else encounters the problem, they know what to do).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Script execution process won't complete because of insufficient permissions to access network.
We won't get any error message or output redirection.

Steps to give permission: Services--> SQLServer2005--> Properties-->Log on-->This account--> Provide local user credentials. Now restart SQL server then execute above SVN update command it will work. Even we can execute batch file to do this job.